# Whats the difference between xclass and xtype in Sencha Touch?

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm trying to learn Sencha Touch and am struggling with the terms xclass and xtype.  Is xtype an alias for the longer winded version which includes the namespace?  Do I need to use alias to define the xtype?  What does xclass refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is technically no difference between them. 
`xclass` can be used for things that aren't components.

Source: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?194447

Comment: (Copy paste from the same thread i linked above) : alias just defines an xtype for components. It's the type of alias and the name <type>.<name>

So 'widget.cmpname' is saying that the type of alias is a widget and the name is cmpname. For the widget, the name is also the xtype.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't really understand the post about alias.  I think I need to read up on this. To me it seems xtype already creates the alias from 'MyApp.views.MainView' to become { xtype: 'mainview' }? Damn this is hard.